# How to set a relative path to a python interpreter in sublime's Anaconda IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I use a portable install of SublimeText on a USB drive with the Anaconda plugin installed for python work.

[This](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/#python-interpreter-settings) tells me how to change which python interpreter to use.

My issue is that I want to carry a version of python with me on the same USB stick. As you're all probably aware, different computers will assign the stick different drive letters, so I can't just use `E:\MyPython\python.exe`. I need to and hope it's possible to use a relative path. I'm not sure where the path is starting from, so I don't know how many `..\..\..\`etc. I need to add to get to my python.

I'm using (or at least experimenting with using) WinPython or WinPythonZero, since they seem to be the most actively maintained versions of a portable python ecosystem. (I require `pip` in addition to just the plain python interpreter). Has anyone else tried a setup like this? Any help would be awesome! Thanks! Oh, I'm sticking with Python3 as well.

Comment: Of the top of my head, I think one ..\ is sufficient.